# Protractor - Can I use $$(elementLocator).first() for more elements like the second, third and etc..?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium, protractor, karma-jasmine

Can I use `$$(elementLocator).first()` for more elements like the second, third and etc..?

or is it just for the first and the last elements?

For example - I've a drop down list with 5 buttons inside but they have the some properties and I want to click on all of them one by one.. so the first one will be:

```
$$("button.font-sm.md-button.md-ink-ripple").first().click();
```

And how can I click on the second option?

**This is the element properties:**

```
<button class="font-sm md-button md-ink-ripple" type="button" ng-transclude="" ng-click="actionClick(saction, $event)"><span class="ng-binding ng-scope">Message</span></button>
```

I know that it possible to use the Xpath, but i prefer some a stable locator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`get()`](https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.get) function that's built in protractor. `get()` function is a zero index based function. Here's how to use it -

```
$$("button.font-sm.md-button.md-ink-ripple").get(0).click(); //Click first element
$$("button.font-sm.md-button.md-ink-ripple").get(1).click(); //Click second element
```

You can always use [`first()`](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/3.0.0/lib/element.js#L259) and [`last()`](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/3.0.0/lib/element.js#L281) functions that are implementations of `get()` function internally. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use .get(x), where x is the zero-based index of an item.

```
$$("button.font-sm.md-button.md-ink-ripple").get(1).click(); //Click second item
$$("button.font-sm.md-button.md-ink-ripple").last().click(); //Click last item
```